# choosing the correct option to display the integers

Tags: java, file

I was solving a puzzle in which i have the below class ..

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    File file = new File("temp.test");
    FileOutputStream stream =new FileOutputStream(file);
//****in comments we have to write integers.... ******
```

Now with me there are four choices which I  am mentioning below can you please advise by putting which one i can get the result as  that will write the integers 0 through 9..

1 st choice is ...

```
DataOutputStream filter = new DataOutputStream(stream);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    filter.writeInt(i);         
}
```

2nd choice is ..

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    file.writeInt(i);
}
```

3rd choice is

```
for (int i=0; i<10 ;i++)
{
    stream.writeInt(i);
}
```

4th choice is

```
DataOutputStream filter = new DataOutputStream(stream);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    filter.writeInt(i);     
}
```

5th choice is ..

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{   
    stream.write(i);
}
```

Comment: In what context are you looking for correct approach? Explain a bit more.

Comment: Also did you try any of those? If so, what went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Use a `PrintWriter` It has the advantage that it buffers writes to reduce IO:

```
try (PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `BufferedOutputStream` not `BufferedWriter`. use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n` to make sure platform specific new line but not needed in case of binary file.

Comment: I edited the solution to use a PrintWriter, which is more convenient regardless.

Comment: `BufferedWriter` is used for character oriented file.

Comment: As per the post, OP is using `Stream` that is used for `binary` file.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any reason to use a `Stream`. At least, that was never specified in the question.